# Android NullPointerException in onCreate

Tags: android

My project has a NullPointerException when creating the main activity. The main activity creates a fragment, which is where the exception lies.
Here's the code for the part where it breaks:
Fragment code:

```
Drawable red;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    red = ((ImageView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.drawable.icon_0)).getDrawable();
}
```

Activity code:

```
private ProblemFragment problemFrag;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);   
    problemFrag = new ProblemFragment();

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = bar.newTab().setText("Problem Fragment").setTabListener(new MyTabListener(this, dashboardFrag));

    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

It crashes when it's running past the red drawable. Is this because of the "getActivity()" line? It is imperative to have these values instantiated immediately, but I can't think of a way to load them up without using findById. If it helps, they are PNG files in the res folder.

Comment: Do you call setContentView in your Activity before showing the Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution in that situation is using `getResources().getDrawable()` methods like that :

```
red = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_0);
```

Please use it to every drawables, etc. in your `res` folder.

Comment: I did that, and now I'm getting an IllegalStateException stating that the fragment is not properly attached to the activity.

Comment: The getActivity was what was causing the NullPointerException earlier though... :/

Comment: Yeah, it caused a NullPointerException.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it myself. I made red a default variable and then initialized it from the main activity's onCreate.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Drawable red = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_0);
```

For all your resources that are not declared views in your xml